# Retrieve previous requests profiling data

Tags: mvc-mini-profiler

I have incorporated the mini-profiler in mvc app but I have a question. When I have a controller looking like below I can't see the execution that took place, any ideas?

1. Controller1.Action1 executes and then does RedirectToAction(Action2)
2. Action2 is run

My problem is that I can't seem to get the execution of step 1 above only step 2. Yes I know that it is a client side redirect involved.

Comment: For now I have added a log statement with the id for each request which I then use and make a call to /mini-profiler-results.

Comment: I ended up emitting the profiler results to my log-file. If interested see http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/issues/detail?id=36

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab the latest version from the repo, we now display the last N requests that were not displayed, per user.

This way we track redirects and POSTs

Comment: Is there a way to disable this behaviour? It means that if you try and conditionally render the profiler, it shows all past requests when the condition becomes true.

I'd like to conditionally render it here, since I'm using the profiler elsewhere for request timings and don't want to disable it.